# How to install old TensorFlow versions without pip

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pip

I need to run code from a paper entitled [minuextractnet](https://github.com/deshuttam/MINU-EXTRACTNET).
However, to properly execute this code I need to fulfil some requirements:

```
Python 2.7, Tensorflow 1.7.0, Keras 2.1.6.
```

Is it possible to run this on Google Colab?

How can I install this old version TensorFlow and Keras?

Comment: Did you try to install tensorflow with conda? A more complex approach would be to [build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

Comment: Yes, but without success

Answer (score 1):

To install an older version of TensorFlow(1.7.0) and Keras(2.1.6) without using pip directly, you can manually download the wheel files from the TensorFlow website and install them. please follow this [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)

> Is it possible to run this on google colab?

Colab has stopped updating Python 2 runtimes, and is gradually phasing out support for Python 2 notebooks.

Colab recently stopped support for Tensorflow Versions older than 2.8v.